# Hide price and add to cart form for purchased product

Tags: 7, theming, commerce

I'm using Drupal 7 and [Drupal Commerce](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce).

I need to hide the price and the add to cart form when a product was bought by the current user.

I found the solution for the add to cart form, but not for the price.

I imagine that it is necessary to use the function hook_entity_view_alter, but my code doesn't work. Here he is :

```
function mymodule_entity_view_alter(&$build, $type) {
  $purchased_product = mymodule_get_users_purchased_products();

  $line_item = commerce_unit_price[LANGUAGE_NONE]['0']['amount'];
  $product = commerce_product_load($line_item->commerce_product[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['product_id']);

      if (in_array($product->product_id, $purchased_product)) {
        $build['product:commerce_price']['#access']=FALSE;
      }
    }
```

Function for load the purchased product :

```
mymodule_get_users_purchased_products() {
      $purchased_products = &drupal_static(__FUNCTION__);

      if (!isset($purchased_products)) {
        global $user;
        $query = db_select('commerce_order', 'corder');
        $query->join('commerce_line_item', 'li', 'corder.order_id = li.order_id');
        $query->join('field_data_commerce_product', 'prod', 'li.line_item_id = prod.entity_id');
        $query->condition('corder.uid', $user->uid, '=')
              ->condition('corder.status', 'completed', '=')
              ->fields('prod', array('commerce_product_product_id'));
        $result = $query->execute();

        $purchased_products = array_unique($result->fetchCol());
      }

      return $purchased_products;
    }
```

Do you know where from comes the problem?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Your code snippet is not correct. However, your general approach is right. You just need to test for the right value and hide the fields you do not want to be seen.

Comment: The problem comes mainly from the line concerning the line item, right ? Would you have some documentation on this matter?

Comment: How were you able to hide the Add to Cart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a function that you can use to accomplish your goals. I tested it with Commerce Kickstart 2.

```
function MYMODULE_entity_view_alter(&$build, $type) {
  if ($build['#view_mode'] != 'full' && $build['#entity_type'] != 'node' || empty($build['field_product'])) {
    return;
  }

  // Load your purchased products.
  $purchased_products = array('HAT2-BLK-OS');

  foreach ($build['#node']->field_product[LANGUAGE_NONE] as $product_data) {
    $products[] = $product_data['product_id'];
  }

  $all_products = commerce_product_load_multiple($products);
  if (count($all_products) == 1) {
    $product = reset($all_products);
    if (in_array($product->sku, $purchased_products)) {
      $build['product:sku']['#access'] = FALSE;
      $build['field_product']['#access'] = FALSE;
    }
  }
}
```

Let's step through it. The first thing that happens is that you need to get your SKUs that you'll base your hiding off of. Just replace this line with a line that loads the products that the current user has purchased.

```
  $purchased_products = array('HAT2-BLK-OS');
```

Then, you load the products:

```
  foreach ($build['#node']->field_product[LANGUAGE_NONE] as $product_data) {
    $products[] = $product_data['product_id'];
  }
```

If you just have a single product per page, you could grab a single `product_id`.

Then you need to load your products.

```
  $all_products = commerce_product_load_multiple($products);
```

I'm assuming a single SKU per product here, so it does `reset($all_products)` to grab the first one. Then, just do a check to see if that product's SKU is in the array of SKUs that were already purchased:

```
    if (in_array($product->sku, $purchased_products)) {
      $build['product:sku']['#access'] = FALSE;
      $build['field_product']['#access'] = FALSE;
    }
```

If it, then hide the sku (in `product:sku`) and the add to cart form (in `field_product`). The result will then be this:

[image]

As opposed to this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks nvahalik for this detailed answer, it works perfectly. A thing: it hides fields for all the users. So that it works only for products bought by the current user, this function can work (basing on the sku)? I have to adapt the $purchased_products to load the purchased products by the current user?

Comment: You'll need to edit the code (see my edit above) so that you grab a list of purchased products.

Comment: It works perfectly, I had forgotten of completed the command... thanks a lot!